# No results for confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) in stata

Tags: stata

I obtained data from a survey (n=139) and have a problem with the CFA.
I have six independent variables whose validity I would like to check with a CFA. For three of the variables this is not a problem (the variables have 6-10 items each).
With the other three variables, however, I do not get a "correct result" with the CFA. For example, the value for Chi Square = 0 (p>chi2 is only displayed as .). Also, for example, the RMSEA value = 0 and the values for CFI and TLI = 1. However, with my small sample size, it is of course impossible to get such good values.
This is the case for all three variables. The variables have in common that they are each measured with only 3 items and I am afraid that this is where the problem lies. On the other hand, the literature usually states that a CFA can be performed for variables with 3 items.

I calculate the CFA with the following code (here: variable "optimism", measured with 3 Items)

```
sem(OPTIMISM -> op01_01 op01_02 op01_03)

estat gof, stats(all)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before or have an idea how I can solve it?

EDIT Stata data are

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(op01_01 op01_02 op01_03)
3 4 4
1 1 1
4 4 5
4 3 4
1 1 1
4 4 4
3 5 5
3 3 5
5 5 5
4 4 4
2 3 2
3 1 3
4 4 4
1 1 1
3 2 5
3 4 5
2 3 4
3 4 5
2 3 4
1 2 2
2 3 3
2 4 3
3 4 4
3 2 5
3 3 5
4 4 4
1 3 2
2 3 3
1 1 5
2 3 3
2 4 4
4 4 4
2 2 2
3 3 2
1 2 2
2 2 3
3 3 3
2 2 2
3 4 4
3 4 3
2 3 4
5 3 5
5 5 5
3 5 4
2 2 3
3 2 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
2 2 2
3 3 5
3 5 5
3 5 5
4 4 4
1 1 3
2 3 3
2 4 3
4 5 5
3 4 4
5 5 5
5 5 5
2 2 2
3 4 4
4 2 4
4 4 5
3 4 4
2 4 3
2 4 4
4 4 4
4 4 4
2 3 3
3 4 4
4 4 4
1 2 2
2 3 2
4 4 4
2 2 3
3 4 3
3 5 4
3 5 5
1 2 4
3 3 3
3 4 5
5 2 3
4 4 2
3 3 3
2 4 5
2 2 3
3 2 3
4 4 4
4 4 4
3 4 5
1 2 1
1 1 2
3 3 4
4 4 4
2 4 4
2 2 1
3 4 4
2 4 4
3 2 4
4 4 5
3 2 4
4 5 1
4 4 5
2 3 4
2 4 4
3 4 4
5 5 5
4 4 4
4 4 4
2 2 2
5 4 5
5 5 5
3 3 4
4 3 4
4 5 5
2 2 3
1 1 3
2 3 5
2 4 5
4 5 5
3 4 5
4 4 4
4 5 4
3 2 3
4 4 4
4 4 5
5 5 5
2 2 3
3 3 3
3 4 4
1 1 1
4 4 4
2 3 1
2 2 3
2 3 3
end
```

and some results are

```
. sem(OPTIMISM -> op01_01 op01_02 op01_03)

Endogenous variables

Measurement:  op01_01 op01_02 op01_03

Exogenous variables

Latent:       OPTIMISM

Fitting target model:

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -552.45222  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -552.45222  

Structural equation model                       Number of obs     =        136
Estimation method  = ml
Log likelihood     = -552.45222

 ( 1)  [op01_01]OPTIMISM = 1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              |                 OIM
              |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Measurement   |
  op01_01     |
     OPTIMISM |          1  (constrained)
        _cons |   2.919118   .0947675    30.80   0.000     2.733377    3.104859
  ------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  op01_02     |
     OPTIMISM |   1.078338   .1302009     8.28   0.000     .8231493    1.333527
        _cons |   3.330882   .0970227    34.33   0.000     3.140721    3.521043
  ------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  op01_03     |
     OPTIMISM |   .9573866   .1205708     7.94   0.000     .7210722    1.193701
        _cons |   3.647059   .0983918    37.07   0.000     3.454214    3.839903
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
var(e.op01_01)|   .4601537   .0907432                      .3126399    .6772694
var(e.op01_02)|   .3950362   .0960129                      .2453317    .6360922
var(e.op01_03)|   .6188597   .0996698                       .451339     .848558
 var(OPTIMISM)|   .7612455   .1547421                      .5110894    1.133842
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test of model vs. saturated: chi2(0)   =      0.00, Prob > chi2 =      .
```

Comment: This seems more of a statistical issue than a problem with your code that we can explore. If you show us the results of `list op01_01 op01_02 op01_03 if !missing(op01_01, op01_02, op01_03)` the problem would be easier to think about.

Comment: Thanks for providing data. I have no experience with these models. My best guess remains that this hinges on statistical understanding, but if that's wrong, sorry, but I have no idea what to do instead. You're better off asking this on Statalist, although at the time of writing that forum is not online.